# p-dialog from primeng 9.1.2 in Angular 9.1.3 is display directly on my component instead of an overlay

Tags: angular, overlay, primeng

As explain in the title, On the click, I can display what I want but not in an overlay windows as expected.

Here is my html code :

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <img style="width: 75px;" (click)="showGenresExclus()" src="url">
</div>
<p-dialog [(visible)]="displayGenresExclus">
 <div *ngFor="let genre of genresExclus">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label for="{{ genre }}">{{ genre }} : </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ genre }}" (change)="genreSelected()" class="form-control">
  </div>    
 </div>
</p-dialog>
```

my TypeScript code:

```
public showGenresExclus(){
this.displayGenresExclus = true;
}
```

And in case you want all my dependencies version (because I was on Angular 10 with primeng 8 and remove all this morning but still not working):

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.7",
"@angular/animations": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/cli": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/common": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/core": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/material": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/router": "^9.1.3",
"@ngtools/webpack": "^9.1.3",
"angularx-social-login": "^2.3.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"primeng": "^9.1.2",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"typescript": "^3.6.5",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
},
```

I've tried almost all properties describe at https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dialog.

I've been on all forums where some questions were like mine but fact is, displaying is good, just not in an overlay and I want that.

Comment: works well on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo-k1wghz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @user1844923 Indeed, I don't know why not for me. still trying to figure out. I'll post what I do if it finally work, I suspect a wrong version of something, have to investigate.